# display data from database by type input box in codeigneter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, input

i have some code this code is working ,, i a use it in codeigneter here my code
 this my db

```
====================
= id = type = name =
====================
= 1  = 3   = adam  = 
= 2  = 2   = julia = 
====================
```

that my database,  name is customer 
and this my controler

```
{   $data['customer'] = $this->usermodel->get_all_customer();
    $this->template->set('title','Tambah User Baru | MyWebApplication.com');
    $this->template->load('template','indoprisma/pemesanan',$data);
       }
```

and my model

```
function get_all_customer()
{
$this->db->from('customer');
return $this->db->get();
}
```

and this my view

```
<?php 
$jsArray = "var prdName = new Array();\n";
echo '<select name="id_cus" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">';
echo '<option>-------</option>';
 foreach($customer->result() as $row)
               {
                  $array_customer[$row->id] = $row->id;
    echo "<option value = ".$row->id.">".$row->id."</option>";
    $jsArray .= "prdName['" . $row->id . "'] = {name :'" . addslashes($row->name) . "' ,type :'" . addslashes($row->type) . "'};\n";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo $jsArray; ?>
function changeValue(id){
document.getElementById('name').value = prdName[id].name;
document.getElementById('type').value = prdName[id].type;

};
</script>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
      <input name="type" type="text" id="type" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
```

i want to change that combobox into a input box , help me please

Comment: here's something I may not know that you can perhaps teach me. In your controller, I see you are using `$this->template->set` and `$this->template->load`, why do you do it like that rather than `$this->load->view()`? I ask because your view is using PHP and I would assume the only reason to use a different templating library would be to not use PHP in your views. Please let me know when you can. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problems here, you're trying to create JavaScript through PHP, then embed it to a script, and on top of that, creating objects you don't really need.. many problems here. You should never try to create JavaScript through PHP. This is what I would do to fix it:

1. Your model should return a `result()`. So you need to change it like this:

   ```
   function get_all_customer() {
     $this->db->from('customer');
     $q = $this->db->get();
     return $q->result(); ///change
   }
   ```
2. Your view should be more HTML, and the least amount of PHP possible. Also, use PHP's function, in this case, `json_encode()` will come in handy. Redo it like this:

   ```
   <select name="id_cus" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
     <option>-------</option>
     <?php foreach ($customer as $row) { ?>
       <option value='<?= json_encode($row) ?>'><?= $row->id ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
   </select>
   <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
   <input name="type" type="text" id="type" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
   ```
3. Lastly, your Javascript like this:

   ```
   <script>
   function changeValue(value) {
     var obj = JSON.parse(value);
     document.getElementById('name').value = obj.name;
     document.getElementById('type').value = obj.type;
   }
   </script>
   ```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my way can help you, here's how I solve the same case as you:

1. For controllers, yours is right.
2. for the model, I think it should be like this

```html
function get_all_customer()
    {
    $hsl = $this->db->query("Select * FROM customer")->result();
    return $hsl
    }
```

3. For coding views, I think like this

```html
 <select name="id_cus" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
    <option value="0">-------</option>
    <?php 
    $jsArray = "var prdName = new Array();\n";
     foreach($customer as $row)
      {
        echo "<option value = ".$row->id.">".$row->id."</option>";
        $jsArray .= "prdName['" . $row->id . "'] = {namee :'" . addslashes($row->name) . "' ,typee :'" . addslashes($row->type) . "'};\n";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
         <input name="type" type="text" id="type" size="20" readonly="readonly" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
    function changeValue(id){
    document.getElementById('name').value = prdName[id].namee;
    document.getElementById('type').value = prdName[id].typee;
    };
    </script>
```

Hopefully my opinion can help your coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Selamat pagi.

By the way, why did you need to convert it into an input?

Is that combobox is retrieving a many data record?

If yes, then you must not change it into an input.

If you want it, try this :

```
$jsArray = "var prdName = new Array();\n";
$customer->result() as $row;
$array_customer[$row->id] = $row->id;
echo "<input type='text' name='id_cus' onchange='changeValue(this.value)' value = " . $row->id . ">";
$jsArray .= "prdName['" . $row->id . "'] = {name :'" . addslashes($row->name) . "' ,type :'" . addslashes($row->type) . "'};\n";
```